# On line 21 it says there is a syntax error. error code e0001

Tags: python

---

I am making a programming language lexer and there is a syntax error but I do not understand why it doesn't work. It says the syntax error is error code e0001. Can anyone help me to undertsand why this code doesn't work?

```
from sys import *

tokens = []

def open_file(filename):
    data = open(filename, "r").read()
    return data

def lex(filecontents):
    tok = ""
    state = 0
    string = ""
    filecontents = list(filecontents)
    for char in filecontents:
        tok += char
        if tok == " ":
            if state == 0:
                tok = ""
        else:
            tok = " "
        elif tok == "\n":
            tok = ""
        elif tok == "typ":
            tokens.append("typ")
            tok = ""
        elif tok == "\"":
            if state == 0:
                state = 1
            elif state == 1:
                tokens.append("STRING: " + string + "\"")
                string = ""
                state = 0
                tok = ""
        elif state == 1:
            string += tok
            tok = ""
    print(tokens)

def run():
    data = open_file(argv[1])
    lex(data)

run()
```

---

#### Error Message:

```
  File "coot.py", line 21
    elif tok == "\n":
       ^
```

Comment: provide the error stacktrace in the question

Comment: File "coot.py", line 21
    elif tok == "\n":
       ^

Comment: elif after else is not allowed.

Comment: You can't do `elif` after `else`. `else` captures **all** the cases that weren't handled before, and is the end of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You typed:

```
if state == 0:
    tok = ""
else:
    tok = " "
elif tok == "\n":
    tok = ""
```

When you said `else` you essentially ended the if check. so just move the `else` block to the end of the `if` block. like this:

```
from sys import *

tokens = []

def open_file(filename):
    data = open(filename, "r").read()
    return data

def lex(filecontents):
    tok = ""
    state = 0
    string = ""
    filecontents = list(filecontents)
    for char in filecontents:
        tok += char
        if tok == " ":
            if state == 0:
                tok = ""

        elif tok == "\n":
            tok = ""
        elif tok == "typ":
            tokens.append("typ")
            tok = ""
        elif tok == "\"":
            if state == 0:
                state = 1
            elif state == 1:
                tokens.append("STRING: " + string + "\"")
                string = ""
                state = 0
                tok = ""
        elif state == 1:
            string += tok
            tok = ""
        else:
            tok = " "
    print(tokens)

def run():
    data = open_file(argv[1])
    lex(data)

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You mismatched the if -> elif -> else statement,

```
for char in filecontents:
    tok += char
    if tok == " ":
        if state == 0:
            tok = ""
    elif tok == "\n":
        tok = ""
    elif tok == "typ":
        tokens.append("typ")
        tok = ""
    elif tok == "\"":
        if state == 0:
            state = 1
        elif state == 1:
            tokens.append("STRING: " + string + "\"")
            string = ""
            state = 0
            tok = ""
    elif state == 1:
        string += tok
        tok = ""
    else:
        tok = " "
```